# The union of singleton sibsignatures always equal the parent signature, even when the parent is not abstract?

Tags: alloy

In the below Alloy model there are three singleton subsignatures (Tom, John, and Barb). They extend Person. Then there is an assert which says that Person consists solely of Tom, John, and Barb. I expected the Alloy Analyzer to generate a counterexample, but it did not. Why? Person is not abstract, so there may be persons not in (Tom + John + Barb), right? Curiously, when I remove "one" from each subsignature, then the Analyzer generates a counterexample. I'm confused. Would you explain what's happening here please?

```
sig Person {}

one sig Tom extends Person {}
one sig John extends Person {}
one sig Barb extends Person {}

assert No_Person_Not_In_The_Extension_Signatures {
   Person = (Tom + John + Barb)
}

check No_Person_Not_In_The_Extension_Signatures
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the default scope is 3. Check in a scope of 4 and you'll see the counterexample:

```
sig Person {}

one sig Tom extends Person {}
one sig John extends Person {}
one sig Barb extends Person {}

assert No_Person_Not_In_The_Extension_Signatures {
   Person = (Tom + John + Barb)
}

check No_Person_Not_In_The_Extension_Signatures for 4
```